# On ionic cordova file.copyFile error = FileError { code: 5, message: "ENCODING_ERR" }

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

**My copy File function is here:**

```
 copyFileToLocalDir(namePath, currentName, newFileName) {
    debugger;
    this.file.copyFile(namePath, currentName, this.file.externalDataDirectory, newFileName).then(
      success => {
        debugger;
        this.updateStoredImages(newFileName);
        // this.presentToast('Success while storing file.');
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        // this.presentToast('Error while storing file.');
      });
  }
```

Please help me to solve this issue